# Websocket connection fails on google compute engine instance

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, google-compute-engine

I am testing a chat service application (javascript and java) that uses javascript websocket connection. Everything works fine on my own machine. I deployed the application on my Google compute engine (GCE) instance. When I tried to use the chat service the connection fails (error code: 1006). I will post the relevant code below

The javascript code for websocket connection is

```
            var server;
            try {
                server = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host +
                        '<c:url value="/chat/${chatSessionId}" />');
                server.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            } catch(error) {
                modalErrorBody.text(error);
                modalError.modal('show'); 
                return;
            }

            server.onerror = function(event) {
                modalErrorBody.text(event.data);
                modalError.modal('show');
            };
```

I tried the following alternatives

1. Replace the window.location.host with the actual external IP address (*** below) of the instance

`server = new WebSocket('ws://***.***.**.*' + '<c:url value="/chat/${chatSessionId}" />');`

2. Add port number after the external IP address

`server = new WebSocket('ws://***.***.**.*:80' + '<c:url value="/chat/${chatSessionId}" />');`

None of these work. The same error message (error code: 1006)

Here is the java part of the code:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{sessionId}",
        encoders = ChatMessageCodec.class,
        decoders = ChatMessageCodec.class,
        configurator = ChatEndpoint.EndpointConfigurator.class)
@WebListener
public class ChatEndpoint implements HttpSessionListener
{
    private static final String HTTP_SESSION_PROPERTY = "com.wrox.ws.HTTP_SESSION";
    private static final String WS_SESSION_PROPERTY = "com.wrox.http.WS_SESSION";
    private static long sessionIdSequence = 1L;
    private static final Object sessionIdSequenceLock = new Object();
    private static final Map<Long, ChatSession> chatSessions = new Hashtable<>();
    private static final Map<Session, ChatSession> sessions = new Hashtable<>();
    private static final Map<Session, HttpSession> httpSessions =
            new Hashtable<>();
    public static final List<ChatSession> pendingSessions = new ArrayList<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("sessionId") long sessionId)
    {
        ...
    }
    @OnMessage
    ...
    @OnClose
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that in the server.xml of the tomcat, the following part is commented out which causes the problem

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```